# Javascript change a picture when clicking

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function to change my pic what is the problem?
my aim is when clicking on a pic toggle between 2 images if image p is showing by clicking shows me image p1

I have this in script:

```
  <script>
  function changeimage()
  {
   if(this.getElementById('myimage').src=="../../images/p1.gif")
   {

    document.getElementById('myimage').src="../../images/p.gif";
   }
  else
   {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src="../../images/p1.gif";
   }
  }
  </script>
```

in the html part I have these ones which are more than one picture but I set the whole of them with Id=myimage is it wrong to set the whole one same ID?:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><img id='myimage' src="../../images/p1.gif" onclick="changeimage();setTable('table2');setTable('table2-2');check('table3');check('table3-3');check('table3-3-3');check('table4');check('table5');check('table6');check('table6-1');"></td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;font-size:13;  font-family:arial,verdana;" width="25%">General Rule Options</td>
    <td valign="bottom" width="100%">
```

I have many rows in my tables like this

Comment: What's wrong? What happens? Where do you call the function?

Comment: please tell me where I am wrong! i have images in my table and in html!

Comment: Because you hadn't provided enough detail.

Comment: Slaks and others would you please not votting me down? it is risky for me after votting down I can't ask questions again

Comment: @Negin: then you should learn how to ask better questions.  Always add as much detail as possible, post any error messages you're getting.  Asking people not to down vote poor questions will likely get you more down votes.

Comment: Thank you Andy yes! you are absolutly right. i appologize

Comment: If you don't want downvotes, [ask better questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
if(this.getElementById('myimage').src=="../../images/p1.gif")
```

In particular, it's the use of `this`. In your function `this` will refer to the window, and the window doesn't have a `getElementById` method. Use `document` like you have in the other cases:

```
if(document.getElementById('myimage').src=="../../images/p1.gif") {
    //...
}
```

And it looks like it should work fine. Alternatively, you can pass in an a reference to the clicked element when you call the event handler, and reference that instead of using `getElementById`. For example:

```
onclick="changeimage(this);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function on click like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ca9m/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="special" src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg" alt ="none">

<script>
$("img#special").click(function () { 
  if($(this).attr("src") == "http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg")
    {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://gcaptain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/image5.png");
    }
    else
    {
     $(this).attr("src", "http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg");
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assuming Negin is able to recognise your code as requiring jQuery, and further assuming it is acceptable to introduce jQuery just to fix a function that almost works as is.

Answer (score 0):

You call `changeImage()` from the `<img>` element, and then reference `this` inside the function.   Since the function runs without context (it's not tacked onto an object), `this` would refer to the `window` object, which doesn't have `getElementById`.

In your HTML, change `onclick="changeImage()` to `onclick="changeImage(this)` and change your `changeImage` function to work with the argument passed instead:

```
  function changeimage(img) {
      if(img.src=="../../images/p1.gif")
          img.src="../../images/p.gif";
      else
          img.src="../../images/p1.gif";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it will refer to window and not the source

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement it should be `document.getElementById()` not `this.getElementById()`.

Though having said that, you can pass a reference to the clicked element in to your function:

```
<img onclick="changeImage(this);">

function changeImage(imgEl) {
   if(imgEl.src=="../../images/p1.gif") {
      imgEl.src="../../images/p.gif";
   } else {
      imgEl.src="../../images/p1.gif";
   }
}
```

That way if all of your table rows are using the same two images they can all call the same function. Better than having the function hardcoded to a particular element's ID.

Comment: `this` won't refer to the element associated with the event because it's not passed into the event handler. `this` will refer to the window.

Comment: @James Allardice - Yes, I realised that right after I posted and went back and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you use a relative path like:

```
<img src="../../images/p1.gif" onclick="changeimage();" />
```

The browser may secretly turn it into an absolute path like:

```
<img src="http://example.com/somewhere/images/p1.gif" onclick="changeimage();" />
```

At least Internet Explorer 9 exposes this behavior. However, you shouldn't depend on this behavior.

There are at least two ways how you can solve this problem:

1. Use `data-` attributes. You add a custom attribute to your image tag:

   ```
   <img src="../../images/p1.gif" data-image="p1" onclick="changeimage();" />
   ```

Then change your JavaScript function to this:

```
<script>          
function changeimage()          
{          
    if(this.getElementById('myimage').getAttribute("data-image") == "p1") {
        document.getElementById('myimage').src="../../images/p.gif";
        document.getElementById('myimage').setAttribute("data-image", "p");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('myimage').src="../../images/p1.gif";
        document.getElementById('myimage').setAttribute("data-image", "p1");
    }
}
</script>
```

1. Use a variable to accomplish the same thing as above.

   ```
   <img src="../../images/p1.gif" onclick="changeimage();" />
   ```

And the JavaScript:

```
    <script>
    var image = "p1";
    function changeimage()
    {
        if(image == "p1") {
            document.getElementById('myimage').src="../../images/p.gif";
            image = "p";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('myimage').src="../../images/p1.gif";
            image = "p1";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

---

I prefer the first method because it allows me to include all information about the image *in the image itself* and not in a variable declared several lines away.